# Javascript reverse modulus with heights

Tags: javascript

In a jQuery slider I have set the default value of `66` which using the below function creates `5' 6"`

How would I be able to reverse the function so if someone put in `6' 2"` I would get a new value like my default one.

```
function getHeight (value) {
    feet = Math.floor(value / 12);
    inches = Math.floor(value % 12);
}
```

Comment: `var res = feet*12+inches`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function getHeight (value) {
    var array = value.split("'"); // [6, 2"]
    var feet = array[0]; // 6
    var inches = array[1].split("\""); //2
    var totalHeight= Number(feet*12) + Number(inches[0]); // 66
    return totalHeight;
}
```

now you can use `getHeight("6'6\"")`